# Is getting the time of an AS3 MovieClip in JavaScript, possible?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

Just a quick feasbility question. We're discussing a custom AS3 movie player which will be on a non-flash page that shows different information depending on the time of the video.

If I were to research getting info from a flash clip in JS through AJAX or something else, where would I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with ActionScript to JavaScript communication. There is a thing in AS3 - [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) which provides this functionality.

Then what you should do is to create a JS accessable EventHandler in AS by publishing it from AS towards webpage by

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("addEventListener", yourEventDispatcher.addEventListerener);
```

Then, when a movie is played, you just dispatch events to yourEventDispatcher which in return passes them to JS by

```
ExternalInterface.call(JSFunctionName_from_addEvenet_Listener_call, EventData);
```

Hope, you get the idea; it is really simple.

Comment: It's worth to add that different browsers use different tags to access the swf via js (some use `<object/>` others use `<embed/>`) so it's best to keep in mind to have the same value for the **id** and **name** attributes. Easiest option to keep things safe and simple is to use something like [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). Also **make sure** `allowAccess` is set to `always`

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza A quick note: `allowAccess` should be `AllowScriptAccess`.